# Folders with more than 40.000 files

Tags: powershell

I have this script I received to check folders and subfolders on a network drive. I wonder how it could be modified into checking only folders and subfolder and write in the CSV if there is any folder with more then 40.000 files in it and the number of files. The image show a sample output from the script as it is now and I do not need it to show any files as it currently do.

```
$dir = "D:\test"

$results = @()

gci $dir -Recurse -Depth 1 | % { 

    $temp = [ordered]@{
        NAME            = $_
        SIZE            = "{0:N2} MB" -f ((gci $_.Fullname -Recurse | measure -Property Length -Sum -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).Sum / 1MB)
        FILE_COUNT      = (gci -File $_.FullName -Recurse | measure | select -ExpandProperty Count)
        FOLDER_COUNT    = (gci -Directory $_.FullName -Recurse | measure | select -ExpandProperty Count)
        DIRECTORY_PATH  = $_.Fullname
    }

    $results += New-Object PSObject -Property $temp

}

$results | export-csv -Path "C:\temp\output.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

[image]

Comment: `gci $dir -Recurse -Depth 1` -> `gci $dir -Depth 1 -Directory`

Comment: You may consider the design of your script anyway. You are querying the same folder 3 times for each folder. If there are folders with 40.000 or more files your script will take ages to complete. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of executing so many `Get-ChildItem` cmdlets, here's an approach that uses robocopy to do the heavy lifting of counting the number of files, folders and total sizes:

```
# set the rootfolder to search
$dir = 'D:\test'

# switches for robocopy
$roboSwitches = '/L','/E','/NJH','/BYTES','/NC','/NP','/NFL','/XJ','/R:0','/W:0','/MT:16'

# regex to parse the output from robocopy
$regEx = '\s*Total\s*Copied\s*Skipped\s*Mismatch\s*FAILED\s*Extras' +
         '\s*Dirs\s*:\s*(?<DirCount>\d+)(?:\s+\d+){3}\s+(?<DirFailed>\d+)\s+\d+' +
         '\s*Files\s*:\s*(?<FileCount>\d+)(?:\s+\d+){3}\s+(?<FileFailed>\d+)\s+\d+' +
         '\s*Bytes\s*:\s*(?<ByteCount>\d+)(?:\s+\d+){3}\s+(?<BytesFailed>\d+)\s+\d+'

# loop through the directories directly under $dir
$result = Get-ChildItem -Path $dir -Directory | ForEach-Object {
    $path = $_.FullName  # or if you like $_.Name
    $summary = (robocopy.exe $_.FullName NULL $roboSwitches | Select-Object -Last 8) -join [Environment]::NewLine
    if ($summary -match $regEx) {
        $numFiles = [int64] $Matches['FileCount']
        if ($numFiles -gt 40000) {
            [PsCustomObject]@{
                PATH         = $path
                SIZE         = [int64] $Matches['ByteCount']
                FILE_COUNT   = [int64] $Matches['FileCount']
                FOLDER_COUNT = [int64] $Matches['DirCount']
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        Write-Warning -Message "Path '$path' output from robocopy was in an unexpected format."
    }
}

# output on screen
$result | Format-Table -AutoSize

# output to CSV file
$result | Export-Csv -Path "C:\temp\output.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```